# Aggregate, sum and pivot MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, sum, pivot

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT sub_nine, sum(sub.sub_low_nett) AS points, sub_pid FROM
  (SELECT c.cn_nine as sub_nine, min(rh.rh_nett) AS sub_low_nett, p.id AS sub_pid
    FROM round r, round_hole rh, player p, course_nine c, course_hole ch
    WHERE r.r_id = rh.rh_rid
    AND p.id = r.r_pid
    AND c.cn_nine = r.r_nine
    AND ch.ch_nine = c.cn_nine
    AND rh.rh_hid = ch.ch_no
    GROUP BY p.id, c.cn_nine, ch.ch_no
  ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub_pid, sub_nine
ORDER BY sub_pid
```

Which returns the following result:

```
 |sub_nine|points|sub_pid
 |   1    |  2   |   1
 |   2    |  17  |   1
 |   3    | NULL |   1
 |   1    | NULL |   2
 |   2    | NULL |   2
 |   3    | NULL |   2
 |   1    | NULL |   3
 |   2    |  26  |   3
 |   3    |  4   |   3
 |   1    |  26  |   5
 |   2    |  36  |   5
```

The result set has been looped into a multi-dimensional array, using the `fetch_assoc()` function.

I need to display each of the points totals per player as well as the total of those points (distinctly / uniquely) for each player in a table

I think I need to loop through the initial multi-dimensional array, and probably place into a new array that has been pivoted around the columns rather than rows, but stuck as to how to do this.

The initial query is sorted by `pid`, so I know that as you loop through the array, the rows can be cumulatively totaled.

I also need the final array to be sorted by the new total value per player as well.

```
pid | score1 | score2| score3 | total
```

the data structure is laid out here:
[Gold DB ERD Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk5AA.jpg)

Comment: And what you have tried

Comment: Please mark up your code using the `{}` toolbar button which indents, not with the `"` toolbar button which makes it a quote.

Comment: Please add table schema to Question.

Comment: i have edited the entry to include a link to the DB data design. so far, i have tried to loop through the original array.it got close at one point, but unable to append the final "Total" column without the <td></td> structures getting messed up.

I have also been trying to amend the post-processing on the query resultset, rather than to throw it all into an array to process after.